# How can I add IP address to my post?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ip

" After completing the form, the following information should be displayed: "Product price [product name], is: [calculated gross amount] PLN gross, tax amount is [calculated tax amount] PLN. ” Data from the form are to be saved to a separate CPT. In addition to the data from the form should also sign up IP and date of completing the form." - thats my task

```
if(!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))
{
    $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
}

elseif(!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
{
    $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
}

else
{
    $ip=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}


function cptpost()
{
    //create post object
    $userid=get_current_user_id();
    $my_post=array(
        'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags ($_POST['name']),
        'post_content' => "PRODUCT: " .$_POST['name']. ". PRICE: " .$_POST['price']. " VAT: " .$_POST['vat'].  " %." ,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        
        
        
);


wp_insert_post($my_post);
}
add_action('wp_head', 'cptpost');
```

I don't know how to add the ip address to the 'post_content'
I want in my post something like "PRODUCT: [product], PRICE: [price], VAT: [vat], IP: [ip]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code and moved $ip inside the function. That way the variable is easily accessible from the function itself.

```
function cptpost() {
    if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
    $dateTime = date("Y/m/d g:i:sa")


    //create post object
    $userid = get_current_user_id();
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['name']),
        'post_content' => "PRODUCT: " . $_POST['name'] . ". PRICE: " . $_POST['price'] . " VAT: " . $_POST['vat'] .  " %. IP:".$ip." Date:".$dateTime,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
    );
    wp_insert_post($my_post);
}
add_action('wp_head', 'cptpost');
```

> **Note:** I assume your existing code was working for the post insert part. I just rearranged the code to make sure IP is included.

Comment: Now it works, thank you so so much! Do you know how could I add date and time ofcompleting the form?

"PRODUCT: [product], PRICE: [price], VAT: [vat], IP: [ip] DATE: [day and time]"

Comment: Modified the answer. Mark it as accepted answer if it helps you.

Comment: You helped me very much! I am very grateful!

Comment: Then please mark the answer as accepted. `To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.`